# Adjusting lay-out in a PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, layout, plsql

When I run my procedure I get this:

```
  Patientnr      Patientnaam    Totaalbedrag
  ===================================================
100424          Victorius         8705
222001          Fagel         7800
100500          Younis         6935
666121          Zonneberg         6715
100306          Schiedam         6255
421221          Algera         1635
100003          Chevalier         950
100027          Groothuis         880
100303          Pauwels         630
100304          Quaak         610
```

Is there a way in Oracle to make sure the last column "Totaalbedrag" is as straight as the others?
Here's my code for the print:

```
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(t_pat(i).patientnr||'         '||v_achternaam||'            '                '||TRIM(t_pat(i).totaal_bedrag));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use RPAD to make the data lengths all the same:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
   ( RPAD(t_pat(i).patientnr,20)
     || RPAD(v_achternaam,40)
     || TRIM(t_pat(i).totaal_bedrag)
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

`v_achternaam` is not fixed width.

At the very least, it is *that* field you should [pad](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions140.htm):

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(t_pat(i).patientnr||'         '
                     ||rpad(v_achternaam,20) 
                     ||' '||TRIM(t_pat(i).totaal_bedrag));
```